# How to adjust alarm volume

Tags: android

I am trying to adjust Alarm volume from my application. I am using AudioManager and SeekBar. Anyways i tried a lot of options but alarm is always at full volume. I can adjust notification,media...volume using this type of code just by changing stream...but alarm is just not working.

```
  try
            {
                volumeSeekbar4 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alarm);
                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                volumeSeekbar4.setMax(audioManager
                        .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                volumeSeekbar4.setProgress(audioManager
                        .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));   


                volumeSeekbar4.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
                {
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                    {
                    }


                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                    {
                    }


                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                    {
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                                progress, 0);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I think that alarm volume is set per alarm, with no global default value. Not sure how to access the list of all alarms though.